# Graphic novel ID: Boy contacts spaceship with rock concert

Tags: story-identification, comics

About 12 years ago, I read a graphic novel about a boy who goes on a spiritual kind of journey of discovery.  I can't remember much about it, but in the end, he organizes a rock concert, and the collective energy of the rock concert contacts a space ship, and he and his friends fly away in the space ship.  I recall that they're all dressed in white when they board the space ship.

I suspect this was written in the 70's or 80's.

Is anybody familiar with this?

Comment: Sounds like "Dude, Where's my Car" :-)

Answer (score 4):

## Update [I think I found the graphic novel!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w5jwxrTqoEA)

> I never even knew that the graphic novel existed, I only knew of the album, so I guess thanks are in order! :-)

I may be off base here, but it seems to quite closely follow the story of 2112 by Rush (a music album)

[Wiki link here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2112_(album)).

It is possible that you saw a visualization of this story. I am personally only aware of the album, but the lore of the story goes so much deeper than what the songs reveal, so I'm suspecting that there are further works (possible graphic novels) that explore the setting more deeply.

Some key parts that match your description:

- The album was originally released in **1976**.
- Track 3, titled **Discovery**, consists of the boy finding a guitar. He doesn't know what it is ("what can this strange device be?"), but he figures out that it makes beautiful notes. His mastery of the guitar progresses during the song.
- (not part of your description) The boy presents the guitar to the priests of the Temple of Syrinx, who refuse to listen to him. They call the guitar a toy that is nothing but a distraction.
- The next two songs ("Oracle: The Dream" and "Soliloquy") are about the boy's internal conflict, where he fights with what he feels and what he is told by the priests. In the end, he chooses the guitar. This is where the big solo begins, and the guitar parts "peak" (climax) strongly here. If there ever was a visualization of this story, I would expect this to look like the pinnacle of rock, with imagery very reminiscent of a rock show.
- At the end of the seventh track, at the conclusion of the musical climax, there is a PA announcement that is repeated: *"Attention all Planets of the Solar Federation We have assumed control."* This is implied to be the ascension of their planet; which has been held back by the priests of Syrinx. It is heavily implied that the boy caused this to happen, as his story is the main story, and his personal liberation leads to the liberation of the planets.
- On the back of the album cover, the Rush band members are all dressed in white:

[image]